# What font to use to display these unicode characters in iOS 8+

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unicode, fonts

I'm using Arial font available in the system to display some unicode characters and able to display most of the characters except the following symbols which are part of arrow category :

⟼, ⤎, ⤏

The corresponding unicodes are: \u{27FC}, \u{290E}, \u{290F}

I'm displaying them on UIButton. Any idea what font supports these unicode characters on iOS 8 and above ?

It shows question mark as Arial doesn't support the glyphs for these, Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Appreciate any help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can check their `Unicode`characters on http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode# I'm sure San Francisco font will works perfectly

Comment: @Adolfo When you say _"I'm sure"_, how sure are you? That page is a table of emoji characters, and has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer… none, I'm afraid.

At least not according to this pretty hacky test…

```
extension unichar {
    func isSupportedBy(fontName: String) -> Bool {
        let characters = [self]
        var glyphs: [CGGlyph] = []
        let ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName(fontName as CFString, 15, nil)
        return CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(ctFont, characters, &glyphs, 1)
    }
}

UIFont.familyNames.map({
    UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: $0)
}).joined().forEach({
    for string in ["A", "\u{27FC}", "\u{290E}", "\u{290F}"].map({$0.utf16}){
        if let char = string.first {
            if char.isSupportedBy(fontName: $0) {
                print("\($0) supports \(string)")
            } else {
                print("\($0) does not support \(string)")
            }
        } else {
            print("invalid char \(string)")
        }
    }
})
```

---

```
Copperplate-Light supports A
Copperplate-Light does not support ⟼
Copperplate-Light does not support ⤎
Copperplate-Light does not support ⤏

etc
```

---

EDIT:

Checking the character input window in macOS, it seems that these particular glyphs *are* available in **STIXGeneral-Regular**  and **Apple Symbols** fonts. Maybe you could add one of these as a custom font to your iOS app?

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick test code. May be I'm wrong..but are these unicodes fall within 16bit range to check against utf16 ?

Comment: Well, once the strings are converted to utf16 they still print correctly, so it looks like that is OK

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ashley. I can see one "Apple Symbols.ttc" font in Mac's path /System/Library/Fonts/. I will try using it now and see if that works.

Comment: Worked just by installing the above font to the iOS app, didn't even actually used that font in code but still using Arial. I think iOS looks automatically for a fallback. Thanks @Ashley again :)